# Java Hibernate access @Formula properties for additional validation / enrichment after persistence

Tags: java, hibernate

If I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT_ENTITY")
public class ParentEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    // ... Other fields

    @Column(name="COLUMN_2")
    private String column2;

    // ... Other fields

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD_ENTITY")
public class ChildEntity {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Integer parentId;

    // ... Other fields

    @Formula("(select COLUMN_2 from {schema}.PARENT_ENTITY p where p.ID = PARENT_ID)")
    private String column2;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

When I persist an instance of ChildEntity, the @Formula property is not populated:

```
session.saveOrUpdate(childEntity)

childEntity.getColumn2(); // this equals "" 

childEntity.postValidate() // validation that relies on @Formula values 

// I want to persist if validation succeeds, but not persist if validation fails
session.flush()
```

Is there an efficient way to do this without going out and querying the PARENT_ENTITY every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the query through e.g. `entityManager.createNativeQuery` or maybe use `entityManager.refresh` to refresh the entity.

Comment: session.refresh() is what I was looking for, thanks.